# Manual accesstoken generation using OpenIdConnect Server (ASOS)

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

Im implementing [Aspnet OpenIdConnect Server (ASOS)](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server) in a **asp.net core 1.1** project and im currently trying to implement some integration testing (`xunit` & `moq`) using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer.

The issue i have is manually generating a fake accesstoken with which to populate a `AuthenticationHeaderValue` for the `HttpClient` requests. Searched for a working solution to this but sofar ive been unsuccessful.

*So my question*: Anyone has a tip as how to manually generating accesstokens for TestServer without having to call the token endpoint of ASOS for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ASOS deliberately prevents you from creating tokens from arbitrary places (they can be only generated during OpenID Connect requests), you can directly use the underlying ASP.NET Core APIs to generate fake tokens that will be accepted by the OAuth2 validation middleware:

```
var provider = container.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
var protector = provider.CreateProtector(
    nameof(OpenIdConnectServerMiddleware),
    OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "Access_Token", "v1");

var format = new TicketDataFormat(protector);

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob le Bricoleur"));

var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
    new AuthenticationProperties(),
    OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var token = format.Protect(ticket);
```

That said, it's rarely the most efficient method if you want to test your own token-protected APIs. Instead, I'd recommend setting `HttpContext.User` or using the OAuth2 validation middleware events to use fake identities without involving crypto operations.

You can also mock the `AccessTokenFormat`:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ValidTokenAllowsSuccessfulAuthentication()
{
    // Arrange
    var server = CreateResourceServer();

    var client = server.CreateClient();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "valid-token");

    // Act
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    Assert.Equal("Fabrikam", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}


private static TestServer CreateResourceServer(Action<OAuthValidationOptions> configuration = null)
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder();

    var format = new Mock<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    format.Setup(mock => mock.Unprotect(It.Is<string>(token => token == "invalid-token")))
          .Returns(value: null);

    format.Setup(mock => mock.Unprotect(It.Is<string>(token => token == "valid-token")))
          .Returns(delegate
          {
              var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
              identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "Fabrikam"));

              var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();

              return new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                  properties, OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
          });

    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddAuthentication();
    });

    builder.Configure(app =>
    {
        app.UseOAuthValidation(options =>
        {
            options.AccessTokenFormat = format.Object;

            // Run the configuration delegate
            // registered by the unit tests.
            configuration?.Invoke(options);
        });

        // Add the middleware you want to test here.

        app.Run(context =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
            {
                return context.Authentication.ChallengeAsync();
            }

            var identifier = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(identifier);
        });
    });

    return new TestServer(builder);
}
```

Comment: I like the last approach, but it only seems to work as long as i do not add UseStartup<Startup>() to the builder (just recieved .well-known not accessible error and unauthorized if i comment out all token auth in startup).

Comment: The OAuth2 validation middleware doesn't use discovery (unlike the JWT bearer middleware), so it's likely not what's causing this issue.

Comment: i do use the UseJwtBearerAuthentication in combination with UseOpenIdConnectServer in my app (i use jwt tokens), but i nevertheless tried it with these commented as well. Will do some debugging and see whats causing it.

Comment: I couldnt find a clean way of this solution working by using the production startup directly so created a separate startup file for the integration testserver. This seems to work very well and makes it easy to switch roles and so forth between tests. Thanks for the tips!